# What is the most efficient way to declare an empty stack?

Tags: c++, performance, stack, exit, nullptr

2 classes (not using stack from the library)

Stack and Node

```
int Stack::pop(void)
{
  int ret = 0;
  if (top == nullptr)
  {

      cout<<"Empty";
  }

else
  {
  ret = top->getValue(); //show value
  }

return ret;
}
```

meanwhile in main

```
cout<< myAlreadyDeclaredStack.pop();

output:  Empty0
```

My problem is that a 0 will come after the string (as the method needs to return an int)

Any ideas friends?

Comment: What is your real question? Your title "What is the most efficient way to declare an empty stack?" doesn't really match your question's body (which seems to be about something entirely different).

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely positively want to avoid exceptions (though I don't think they are as inefficient as you think they are), you could do a couple of things.

1. If your stack always stores `int` (or numeric) variables, you could use a predefined "error" return, like `numeric_limits<int>::min()`
2. You could have a version of `pop()` which takes a variable reference, IE `bool pop(int& val)`, change val to the popped value and return false if the stack is empty.

I'm sure there are other solutions, but these two come to mind.  I don't really see why you are so hesitant to use exceptions though, they are basically there for situations like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(top!= NULL)      
 {
    ret = top->getVal();      
 }       
 else     
 {            
 throw "Stack Empty";        
 }

 int main(void)

 try
 {
 cout<< myAlreadyDeclaredStack.pop();
 }
 catch (const char* msg)
 {
  cout<< msg <<endl;
 }
```

Seems ugly to me and having to process the exception everytime  in the method and in the main seems inefficient.

Is it the only way/most efficient way? (after all, a stack is about speed)

Comment: If you can't recover from the exception, don't catch it. Just let it die. What do you want to happen when you pop an empty stack?

Comment: just a message saying it is empty

Comment: You should test the stack to make sure it isn't empty before calling pop.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea but difficult to implement

```
void Stack::isEmpty(void)
{
 if (top == nullptr)
     cout<<" Empty"
 else
     top.pop();
}

 main

 declaredStack.isEmpty();  //wouldn't return a value (to maybe use/manipulate it)
  //, just display it  --if I set it to display in pop()

 //and if I put isEmpty in pop I'm back to having to return a value
```

Comment: Erm, isEmpty should not modify the state of the stack.